# Fragment transaction with viewpager returns blank view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using tablayout with view pager to display fragments. My current setup is that I get a listview of 'Categories' and the user clicks on a category then returns a new fragment containing a list of available discounts within that category.

My setup creates the new DiscountList fragment but does not update the view when the original fragment does its transaction. Could someone help me figure out the correct solution? I am not sure if my viewpager is incorrect or I am missing a step. I can provide more information, if needed. Thanks!

CategoryListFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(container.getId(), DiscountListFragment.newInstance(position))
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

DiscountListFragment.java

```
public static DiscountListFragment newInstance(int categoryId) {
    DiscountListFragment discountListFragment = new DiscountListFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("categoryId", categoryId);
    discountListFragment.setArguments(args);

    return discountListFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        categoryId = getArguments().getInt("categoryId");
    }
    reactiveLocationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(getActivity());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_discount_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

ViewPager.java

```
/**
 * Retrieves the selected tab and returns it. If new tab needs to be added
 * simply increment case and return a new fragment
 * @param position the position of tab selected
 * @return the selected tab
 */

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new HomeFragment();
        case 1:
            return new CategoryListFragment();
        case 2:
            return new MapViewFragment();
        case 3:
            return new MessagesFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace a fragment inside of a ViewPager? Or do you want to replace the entire ViewPager with the new fragment?

Comment: I am trying to replace a fragment inside of a ViewPager.

Comment: I think the best way to do that, is to use a root fragment. So your root fragment would load fragment1 by default, and it can later be replaced with fragment2. Someone already made an example of this and put it on GitHub: https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example
Personally, I would not let a fragment replace itself, but send a callback to the root fragment. But that is really up to you to decide.

Comment: Great! I'll try this and give an update. If you were to approach this a different way which would you recommend? Thanks, Kevin!

Comment: @kevinpelgrims your advice worked! Thank you! :)

Comment: Great! I posted a real answer, in case someone stumbles upon this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to replace a fragment within a `ViewPager` is to create a root fragment that is loaded into the pager. The root fragment loads fragment1 by default, which can later be replaced by fragment2.
Someone made a good example of this and put it up on Github: https://github.com/danilao/fragments-viewpager-example

I would take a slightly different approach than the example, and have the root fragment be responsible for switching the fragments, rather than the child fragment itself. But that is an architectural decision, and is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the container id in your `transaction.replace()` call is wrong.  If `CategoryListFragment` is a paged fragment, then container.getId() is the id of the `ViewPager`.  You don't want that.  You want the id of the container that contains the fragment with the `ViewPager` (one level up).

Comment: Hi Kris, thank you for your response! 

I modified the code to use R.id.contentContainer instead of container.getId(). The new fragment displays, but is on top of every other view. Here are screenshots of the behavior I'm experiencing: http://imgur.com/a/8gaBE

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code.  Is the view with the `ViewPager` set up from an activity rather than a fragment?  That's the only reason I can think of why you would still be seeing the `ViewPager` after the `transaction.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and spent a lot of time. I changed

`mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());`

to

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

of Viewpager fragment.
I got help from [here](https://reformatcode.com/code/android/viewpager-from-fragment-returns-blank)