# Android - Call a fragment inside tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, fragmentmanager

I try to create an application that has two pages. First page is a tabbed page and second page is a detail page.

I create a tapped page using [this guide](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/). I have a mainactivity that contains view pager and 3 tabs(`Tab1, Tab2, Tab3`). Tab3 contains a button to navigate detail page. Each tab has own .java(extends Fragment) and  .xml file. I edit fragmentThree.xml layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragmentThree"]>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/goToDetail"
    android:text="GO TO DETAIL" />
```

I create a new fragment for detail page. I set onclick method inside of Tab3.java;

```
goToDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivity, new Detail());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

When I press the button, it doesn't do anything. I don't replace the fragment.

Comment: on click of the button, do you want to create new tab (a new fragment in your case) or navigate to a new activity to show details ?

Comment: navigate to a new activity to show details.

Comment: Please, provide  all the information in order to help you, are you using support Fragments?, if yes, you should use getSupportFragmentManager instead.

Comment: @miibpa I tried getSupportFragmentManager. It doesn't work.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103263/launching-new-fragment-from-fragment-in-tab-layout-doesnt-hide-the-tabs

Comment: And what is R.id.mainActivity?

Comment: R.id.mainActivity is the layout of main activity class. It constains viewPager and tablayout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment transaction with viewpager returns blank view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535624/fragment-transaction-with-viewpager-returns-blank-view)

Comment: @debo.stackoverflow the solution is not working for me. My root layout has a viewPager and tablayout.

Answer (score 0):

use Frame layout in Main Activity

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent">
```

In clicklistiner :-

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.parent, new Detail());
            transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use you viewpager id instead of main layout id, where you set the tab layout fragment.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, new Detail());
```